# After upgrading my Unity android to 64 bit I still get an error after uploading apk on Google Play. Not compliant 64 bit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

After upgrading Unity to 64-bit, I've applied all options:

- installed NDK
- il2cpp
- armv7
- arm64
- x86
- scripting run time version .NET 4.x

All things done, APK build successfully, but after uploading to Google Play, I get the same error:

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 1.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App
>   Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device
>   architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids
>   increasing the overall size of your app

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently and answered that in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629052/after-upgrading-my-unity-android-to-64-bit-i-still-get-error-after-uploading-apk).

You have to **uncheck x86** (32 bit for Intel processors), otherwise, Google Play store expects that you provide an x86_64 (64 bit Intel processors). Don't confuse those processors with ARM processors **armeabi-v7a (32 bits)** and **arm64-v8a (64 bits)**.

**Edit -> Project Settings -> Player Settings -> Android tab -> Others > deselect x86**

Unity doesn't support x86_64 for Android and is even deprecating x86 support for Android in 2019.2, and removing it completely in the upcoming 2019.3 (currently in Beta), so removing this support is inevitable.

These Intel processors in Android are virtually dead by now, their market share is inexpressive, unfortunately.

In case that this isn't yet the cause of your problem, you need to **certify that you Armv8 (64 bit Arm processor) builds are compiling with all libraries**. Normally you just need to provide them if you install 3rd party plugins or libraries.

**More details**

- [Android Support Update: 64 bit and App Bundles Backported to 2017.4 LTS](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/)
- [Get your apps ready for the 64-bit requirement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html)

Comment: i am using macbook pro and unity 2018.2.1f1 , should i also uncheck x86?

Comment: If you want to submit an Android app (developed in Unity) to Google Play store now, yes, you should UNCHECK x86.

It doesn't matter if you are using a Mac or Windows, what is matter is the target build platform, in this case, Android.